# How to get UIBezierPath around a zone of a given color on a UIImage

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I have a UIImage, most of it is white. When the user taps the screen, I would like to get the contour of the tapped region. E.g. if he taps a white zone on the image, I need a UIBezierPath around that zone. Any suggestions on how should I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be of some use: http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/